# PageMethod vs ajax async call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

I am new asp.net and want to call server side method from java script.
For that I can do this using ajax call and PageMethod.

Now my question is which one is better to use?

```
$.ajax({})
```

Or

```
PageMethods.FunctionName(Parameter);
```

Comment: Juhi this is not a site to get suggestions instead you have to post some code which you tried to do but you stuck there. Although you can go for the ajax.

Comment: I wanted to know which is better/efficient for my web application

Comment: No doubt ajax is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have already put Ajax scrip manager. you can user any method. 
but if you have not put script manager i suggest you should go for Ajax asynchronous call

Page methods are much more openly accessible.and it is not good idea to put script manager just for web method calling

Answer (score 2):

No one can tell better than [Dave Ward](http://encosia.com/about-dave-ward/)

https://web.archive.org/web/20161229045603/http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

**Page methods are much more openly accessible. The relative unimportance of EnablePageMethods is a nice surprise.**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```